# How to quit 'screen' if you don't have \ on the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

To quit `screen` you need to hit `ctrl+a, ctrl+\`. How do you do that if you don't have `\` on the keyboard?

On my keyboard I need to hit `shift+alt+7` to get a backslash - if I'm in an editor. Won't work for `screen` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I meanwhile found was to create `~/.screenrc` and add `bind q quit` to it. This allows me to quit by typing `ctrl+a, q`.